# Como obter datas com intervalo de X dias?

Tags: mysql, sql, data

Eu tenho um campo `data` numa tabela. E todos os dias eu vou pesquisar:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_ADD( data, INTERVAL 7 DAY ) = CURDATE( )
```

Ou seja, se a data da tabela + 7 dias é igual à de hoje. Isto para obter os registos de há 7 dias atrás.

Mas para além desses registos de há 7 dias atrás eu também quero os registos de há 7+7 dias atrás, 7+7+7 dias atrás, etc.

Por exemplo, se hoje for dia `22-11-2019`(CURDATE) eu quero ir buscar todos os registos com datas `15-11-2019`, `08-11-2019`, `01-11-2019` e por ai fora de 7 em 7 dias.

Exemplo no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/usf57EbBmteTvPiPG1EGHb/0).

Comment: Se você conseguir obter a diferença de dias entre `data` e `CURDATE` (talvez `DATEDIFF`?), basta que esta diferença seja múltipla de 7. Se quer as datas estritamente passadas, a diferença necessita ser negativa (ou `data < CURDATE()`); se quer todas as datas menos o da atual, precisa ser diferente de 0

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pode fazer uma resposta?

Comment: Algo como `(DAY(CURDATE()) - DAY(data)) % 7 = 0` ou algo mais otimizado que isso

Comment: @Woss, melhor que converter em dias absolutos e subtrair é só [pegar a diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/421435/64969)

Comment: E se o CURDATE retornar `21-11-2019`, qual seria o retorno esperado?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento todos os registos de `14-11-2019`, `07-11-2019`, `31-10-2019`, etc decrescendo de 7 em 7 dias.

Comment: Uma ultilma duvida, será sempre a partir do CURDATE (o que está especificado na pergunta), ou poderá eventualmente ser filtrado por datas menores? Supondo que a data setada (sendo curdate ou não) será o range máximo.

Comment: Sim será sempre a partir do CURDATE para trás.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verifique se a diferença entre as datas é um múltiplo de 7:

```
select * from tabela where MOD(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), data), 7) = 0;
```

Esse select vai trazer inclusive um registro com `data = CURDATE()`, portanto se não quiser isso acrescente `and data != CURDATE()`. Ou ainda, se quiser estritamente datas anteriores à atual acrescente `and data < CURDATE()` e, claro, nem precisará do `and data != CURDATE()`.

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iSwrA4KTppeC8s4rHM2mJn/2)

Comment: Aliado à verificação de ser o mesmo dia provavelmente serão necessárias a verificação se `data` é anterior à data atual, para não retornar a data 2019-11-21, mesmo hoje sendo 2019-11-14 e a verificação se é o mesmo mês/ano, para não retornar a data 2019-10-31, por exemplo.  solução permanece a mesma, só *preciosismo* para atingir, de fato, o desejado na pergunta.

Comment: @Woss Certo, vou editar

Comment: Uma boa resposta, ainda sim me parece que a pergunta contém alguns detalhes, creio que  a busca espera o retorno dos retroativos apenas, e não da data atual, mas isto por causo do que o AP informou: se hoje for dia `22-11-2019` eu quero ir buscar todos os registos com datas `15-11-2019`, `08-11-2019`, `01-11-2019`, não é nada complicado, seria mais uma condição que o proprio AP resolve aplicando  `select *
from tabela
where date < CURDATE() AND MOD(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date), 7) = 0
ORDER by `date` DESC;` ...

Comment: ... o que inclusive pode resolver outra situação, a de buscas por datas diferentes de CURDATE... Creio que talvez seja isto: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/usf57EbBmteTvPiPG1EGHb/2 (cc @JorgeB. confirma se é isto ou não pra mim por favor)

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento date < CURDATE() já estava na minha resposta

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é isso sim senhor.

Comment: @mari falta de F5 aqui, não vi o edit :) +1 pra resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia utilizar o seguinte `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MOD(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), data), 7) = 0
```

Vamos à explicação:

A função `DATEDIFF()` retorna o intervalo em dias entre a data atual `CURDATE()` e a data inserida em seu banco de dados `data`.

Já a função `MOD()` retorna o resto de um divisão, logo, quanto a divisão for exata este número é múltiplo do parâmetro passado para comparação, no caso, 7, por isso MOD( **intervalo em dias**, *7* ).

Ao final, você deverá fazer um simples comparação para verificar se o resultado retornado pela função `MOD()` é igual a zero (0), indicando que a divisão dos dias por sete é exata.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução será carregares todos os dados para um cursor, e utilizares o valor do intervalo (7) numa variável e vais incrementando com 7 em cada iteração e assim vais buscar todos os intervalos da base de dados, até terminar.

NOTA: Se partilhares o teu exemplo no SQLFiddle, posso ajudar-te com o cursor.

```
SET @interval = -7;
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE `data` >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL @interval DAY;
```

Comment: Adicionei um fiddle na pergunta

Comment: Achei estranho usar cursor para tal fim, e eu particularmente não consigo ver o cursor convergindo para resultado algum (talvez por eu ser ignorante com o uso de cursores). Poderia desenvolver mais a resposta?, ainda mais agora que o AP colocou um fiddle para se basear?